# Efficiently get midpoint of image in Python with astropy

Tags: python, numpy, astropy

My data is organized in a table in fits format (example.fits). I open this table ('mappars') using the Python module `atpy`. The table has columns x,y which are image coordinates and a data column z. 
The x,y are evenly spaced (events on a CCD detector) but there are gaps in between.

I am getting the value in the middle of the image like this:

```
import atpy
import numpy as np

mappars = atpy.Table('example.fits')
#get midpoint value
midx = np.int((np.max(mappars['x'])+np.min(mappars['x']))/2)
midy = np.int((np.max(mappars['y'])+np.min(mappars['y']))/2)
midist = mappars.where((mappars.x == midx) & (mappars.y == midy)['z']
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this (without the .where function which is part of `atpy`)? 
Also is there a function corresponding to .where in `astropy`.table since I would like to move from `atpy` to `astropy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this very similarly using `astropy.io` and `numpy`. I don't have an event file handy, but something like:

from astropy.io import fits
import numpy as np

```
with fits.open("example.fits") as hdulist:
    events = hdulist[1].data   # since hdu 0 should be an ImageHDU type, the events are probably in the first extension
    midx = np.int((np.max(events['x'])+np.min(events['x']))/2)
    midy = np.int((np.max(events['y'])+np.min(events['y']))/2)
    midist = events['z'][(events['x'] == midx) & (events['y'] == midy)]
```

In this case, I'm directly creating a boolean index array to `events['z']` using the boolean (numpy) expression `events['x'] == midx) & (events['y'] == midy)`.

Note that this is untested; if the above fails for you, I can probably try and pull an event file somewhere from the internet to test it, unless of course your event file is peculiar.

---

By the way, if `x` and `y` are, say, *integer* pixel coordinates, you can make things slightly simpler by using pure integer division and skip the cast to int:

```
midx = (np.max(events['x'])+np.min(events['x']))//2
midy = (np.max(events['y'])+np.min(events['y']))//2
```

This works in Python 3 directly, and in Python 2 if you have `from __future__ import division` (you probably should do that anyway).

Comment: Thank you this worked! I only made two small edits to the code to make it work with the specific format of my table. Also `from __future__ import division` worked well (using Python 2.7).

Comment: Nice. Also, your edit was correct but got rejected because it was so specialized the reviewers didn't recognize the (obvious) mistake I had made and your correction. I've fixed that now myself.